# JPA query : select only some fields of my object and then create my object

Tags: jpa, repository, jpql

I have a JPA repository custom query :

```
@Query("Select id, nom, code, codeComptable, typeClient from Client")
List<Object>  findAllWithoutForeignKey();
```

This query returns a Java.Lang.Object :

> [1, TEST X, GUHHR, 1566FR487, TypeClient{id=1, nom='GARAGE',
>   actif='true', dateDerniereModif='2015-01-03'}]

I don't know how to access the values of my object. 
I have tried everything I could think of but I didn't manage to do that.

Does anyone know how to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JPQL query returns an Object **array** just as the JPA spec says it should. So you get each row and cast to `Object[]`. And then you access the elements of the array to get the column values. Basic java